# C++ code run very slow in a predominantly Objective-c project

Tags: c++, objective-c, performance, compiler-construction

I was required to add an exotic image format to a project. The client supplied only a c++ library. The library does it's work extremely slow once compiled in a predominantly Objective-C project (that is, a project with all the rest of the code in objective-c)

I've compared performance with c++ implementations on a Mac and a PC, a ported C# implementation to a pc - all on computers similar to each other (CPU and memory-wise). The slow performance is only in the Objective-C project, much more evident on a device than on the simulator. I would expect a pentalty for the device's (iPad) less-than-mac/pc CPU, but not to go from 0.2 secs image parsing in the simulator to a staggering 2.4 secs per image on the device!
**Does all c++ code added to an Objective-C project perform so slow?**

Tweaked with all compiler kinds, many compiler preferences. Also time-profiled to realize the c++ code takes huge amounts of time on trivial actions (simple instructions such as ++'s and +='s).

How should i approach this in order to get the c++ library's performance to a reasonable level within the objective-c project?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  There is no such thing as an "Objective-C project".  Individual files may be C++ or Objective-C or C or something else.  Each is compiled according to the project settings, independent of what other files are part of the project.  So, there's something else going on here.  Do you mean that you've ported the code to Objective-C from C++ and the ported code is slower?

Comment: I have not ported the code to Objective-c, just embedded cpp in a regular iOs project, with all the rest of the files written in Objective-C

Comment: As you have the C++ source, why don't you use the profiler to check what exactly slows everything down? Maybe it can be optimized for the iPhone/iPad/iPod to perform better?

Comment: Have you verified that the 'trivial' actions really are trivial? In C++, `++` and `+=` aren't necessarily trivial since they can be overloaded to execute arbitrary code, and I believe the only way they *can* show up in profiling results is if they have been overloaded. In particular, `+=` for any kind of collection usually ends up allocating memory.

Comment: I have time profiled the code as suggested - a coworker is helping in optimizing the c++ code. The time profiler shows the heaviest action inside an image parsing sub sub sub function, that basically "decodes" pixels from the exotic image format to bmp bytearray - so it's mainly simple arithmetic, some clamps and some writes to a pre-allocated buffer. I have verified += and ++ were not overloaded. Gained some 25% improvement in performance, but still, 1.4 sec per img on an ipad is unacceptable when on the simulator it gives 0.1 sec...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've compared performance with c++ implementations on a Mac and a PC,
>   a ported C# implementation on a pc - all on similar computers CPU and
>   memory-wise. The slow performance is only in an Objective-C project,
>   much more evident on a device than on the simulator.

iOS devices are relatively powerful considering their size and battery constraints, but they're no match for a modern Mac or PC. You'd expect to find a significant slowdown of any code, C++ or otherwise, when running on a device compared to the simulator. When you say that you tested "all on similar computers" do you mean similar to each other or similar to, say, an iPhone 4?

I don't know of any particular performance penalty attached to using C++ together with Objective-C. You could test for yourself by coming up with some very simple benchmark, coding it in both C++ and Objective-C, and comparing execution times.

Comment: Would using a c++ static / dynamic linking change much?